# Subscribe event for Follow button?

Tags: facebook, events, subscribe

I have read: edge.create - fired when the user likes something (fb:like).

But what's fired when the user follow someone (fb:follow)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like currently there is no solution for that :(

- [Event Subscription Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.9)
- `edge.create` doesn't work for the button